# Linking tkinter GUI with functions in a different module

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want to link GUI (1. modul) with the functions that are in a different module. Basically I need to link GUI with the program.

I created a very easy example:

modul1:

```
from modul2 import *
from tkinter import *


window = Tk()
window.title('Program')
window.geometry("300x300")

text_input= StringVar()

#result
result=Entry(window, textvariable=text_input)
result.place(x=6,y=15)

#Button
button=Button(window, text='X')
button.config(width=5, height=2, command=lambda: test())
button.place(x=10,y=70)

window.mainloop()
```

modul2:

```
import modul1

def test():
    global text_input
    text_input.set('hello')
```

EXPECTED:
This program should write "hello" into Entry window after clicking on a button.

RESULT: ERROR:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ondrej\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/Ondrej/Desktop/VUT FIT/IVS\modul1.py", line 17, in <lambda>
    button.config(width=5, height=2, command=lambda: test())
NameError: name 'test' is not defined
```

Does anybody know where the problem is?
Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: You can put shared objects in a separate module and `import` it in any other module that needs to access one or more of them. Import are cached in `sys.modules`, so that subsequent `import`s in other module will return the cached module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the problem you actually have is to do with a circular import. Modul1 imports Modul2 and Modul2 imports Modul1. a way you could solve this is to give the textinput as a parameter to the test function in modul2 like this:

modul1.py:

```py
import modul2
from tkinter import *


window = Tk()
window.title('Program')
window.geometry("300x300")

text_input = StringVar()

# result
result = Entry(window, textvariable=text_input)
result.place(x=6, y=15)

# Button
button = Button(window, text='X')
button.config(width=5, height=2, command=lambda: modul2.test(text_input))
button.place(x=10, y=70)

window.mainloop()
```

modul2.py:

```py
def test(text_input):
    text_input.set('hello')
```

Unfortunately python really doesn't like you to do circular imports and this is good as this would actually mean an infinite loop. When would it stop importing the other file?

Edit: there would be a very convoluted way to make a class in a third module and set attributes on that, and then import this third module in both modul1 and modul2 to share variables between them but please don't...

Edit2: an example of this:

Modul1.py:

```py
from shared import SharedClass
import modul2
from tkinter import *


window = Tk()
window.title('Program')
window.geometry("300x300")

SharedClass.text_input = StringVar()

# result
result = Entry(window, textvariable=SharedClass.text_input)
result.place(x=6, y=15)

# Button
button = Button(window, text='X')
button.config(width=5, height=2, command=lambda: modul2.test())
button.place(x=10, y=70)

window.mainloop()
```

Modul2.py:

```py
from shared import SharedClass


def test():
    SharedClass.text_input.set('hello')
```

shared.py

```
class SharedClass:
    pass
```

This works due to the way python loads imported classes. They all are the same. This makes it so if you set properties on the class (not the instances of it) you can share the properties.

Comment: But how should I use function without argument? Is that possible?
Or if I want to use this function? This works just in case it is in one module `def btnclick (numbers):
    global operator
    operator=operator + str(numbers)
    text_input.set(operator)`
operator is defined in modul1 in this case as: operator=""

Comment: you would need to add this operator as an argument. But ill write down a little implementation of that convoluted way i mentioned. It isn't very pythonic but it would i think acomplish what you want. But in general the answer is: python cant't do such thing in a pythonic way

Comment: I edited it to include the shared class version which is a similar solution to what  martineau suggests but without the sys.modules

Comment: but in the end the most pythonic way is to just give the function some parameters. maybe more than 1 for the operator

Comment: Minimizing the use of global variables also improves code quality and readability, and is easier to debug as less functions will have side effects.

Comment: So you dont recommend using the solution with shareclass?
The best solution according to you is to have always a parameter in a function

Comment: For sure, having a function take some parameters also enables you to easily work with defaults for reusing the function. The sharedclass is more of a hack than actually something i would use. When debugging having functions do only one thing based on their parameters is very useful. that way you can test that and only that function without needing the context of other functions having set other variables globally. This makes unit testing possible. So i would definitely not recommend the sharedclass but if you really wanted to you can.

Comment: in general when programming, use the global keyword (and global variables in general) as little as possible. the only real usecase would be some constants set for the entire program in my opinion.